# Positioning WebVTT text overlay (subtitles) in four corners of the video

Tags: html, html5-video, webvtt, video-subtitles

I have a problem with positioning WebVTT subtitles. I'd like to have 4 placeholders in four corners of the video to post some additional data along with the video. The problem is, the positioning acts weird and I guess it's kinda hackish way to do this, so if I'm totally abusing WebVTT for this, please let me know in the comment which [generally supported](https://caniuse.com/webvtt) way would be.

Current result I've achieved

[image]

Video to use: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Video test</h1>
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track default src="track.vtt">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

track.vtt file:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000 line:0 align:left position:0% size:50%
AAAAAAAAA

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000 line:0 align:right position:100% size:50% 
BBBBBBBBB

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000 line:100% align:left position:0% size:50%
CCCCCCCCC

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000 line:100% align:right position:100% size:50% 
DDDDDDDDD
```

I've highligted `<video>` element in dev tools.

As you can see, the "A", "B" and "C" subtitles are placed correctly, in the corners of the video. But for some reason, "D" are misaligned and shifted to the left.

Any ideas how to fix this and place "D" in the lower right corner of the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to find some positioning reference on https://www.speechpad.com/captions/webvtt#toc_14

|  | Horizontal Text Direction | Vertical Text Direction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `position:0% align:start` | Left edge of cue box is at left edge of screen. | Top edge of cue box is at top edge of screen. |
| `position:0% align:center` | Center of cue box is at left edge of screen. Left half of box is offscreen. | Center of cue box is at top edge of screen. Top half of box is offscreen. |
| `position:0% align:end` | Right edge of cue box is at left edge of screen. Entire box is offscreen. | Bottom edge of cue box is at top edge of screen. Entire box is offscreen. |
| `position:0%,line-left align:end` | Right edge of cue box is at right edge of screen. | Top edge of cue box is at top edge of screen. |
| `position:50% align:start` | Left edge of cue box is at horizontal center of screen. | Top edge of cue box is at vertical center of screen. |
| `position:50% align:center` | Center of cue box is at horizontal center of screen. | Center of cue box is at vertical center of screen. |
| `position:50% align:end` | Right edge of cue box is at horizontal center of screen. | Bottom edge of cue box is at vertical center of screen. |
| `position:100% align:start` | Left edge of cue box is at right edge of screen. Entire box is offscreen. | Top edge of cue box is at bottom edge of screen. Entire box is offscreen. |
| `position:100%,line-right align:start` | Right edge of cue box is at right edge of screen. | Bottom edge of cue box is at bottom edge of screen. |
| `position:100% align:center` | Center of cue box is at right edge of screen. Right half of box is offscreen. | Center of cue box is at bottom edge of screen. Bottom half of box is offscreen. |
| `position:100% align:end` | Right edge of cue box is at right edge of screen. | Bottom edge of cue box is at bottom edge of screen. |

Comment: Can you show any of these inside a full video track CSS statement?

Comment: @LWC just append it after timestamps inline in vtt file, like this: `00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000 position:99% align:end`

Comment: How about through JavaScript?

Comment: @LWC I didn't use Javascript at all. Just text styling in css (via `video::cue` selector) and positioning by inline styles as mentioned above